# PHP md5 hashing not working

Tags: php, md5

I've got the following PHP code which is used for registering to a website. I'm trying to hash the passwords for security but whenever I submit a dummy registration the passwords are not hashed in phpMyAdmin. They appear normal. Here is my code:

```
<?php

//get the values from the form
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$Username = $_POST['username'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];
$RepeatPassword = $_POST['repeatpassword'];

//encrypt the passwords
md5($Password);
md5($RepeatPassword);

//query the database
$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$Name', '$Username', '$Password')";

if (!mysql_query($query)) {

die('Error ' . mysql_error() . ' in query ' . $query);
} 

//check passwords match
if ($Password !== $RepeatPassword) {
echo "Your passwords do not match. <a href='login.php'>Return to login page</a>";

}

//check to see if fields are blank
if ($Name=="") {
echo "Name is a required field. <a href='login.php'>Return to login page</a>";
}

else if ($Username=="") {
echo "Username is a required field. <a href='login.php'>Return to login page</a>"; 
}

else if ($Password=="") {
echo "Password is a required field. <a href='login.php'>Return to login page</a>";
}

else if ($RepeatPassword=="") {
    echo "Repeat Password is a required field. <a href='login.php'>Return to login page</a>";
}

else {
    $_SESSION["message"] = "You have successfully registered! Please login using your username and password.";
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

The tutorials I have read online have all said to do it as per the above. I've tried putting the two lines of md5 code in numerous places but to no avail.

Comment: "I'm trying to hash the passwords for security" Then why are you using MD5?

Comment: @ceejayoz Truth, MD5 is one of the less secure hashes you can use if security is your goal. Granted this script is so completely overwhelmingly prone to SQL injection that MD5 is probably the most secure part of this page

Comment: Just a university project, not an actual website but nonetheless your points are valid. I'm not exactly an SQL/PHP expert (hence the 'university' part), but I'll look into alternatives.

Comment: wow sql injection and using md5.  poor security.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
md5($Password);
md5($RepeatPassword);
```

This code basically does nothing. You want:

```
$Password = md5($Password);
$RepeatPassword = md5($RepeatPassword);
```

But ultimately, MD5 doesn't do much for security.  Consider [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/), stop using the `mysql_*` functions, and start learning about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Wasn't me. In fact, I upvoted you for your comments about SQL injection lol.

Comment: Thanks. As said above, I'll look into what you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything with the return value of the functions. It should be:

`$Password = md5($Password);`

`$RepeatPassword = md5($RepeatPassword);`

Answer (score -2):

It's not working because you're not assigning your md5 to a variable. Do something like this:

`$Password = md5($Password);`

`$RepeatPassword= md5($RepeatPassword);`

Comment: -1 You just repeated what the other two answers said - almost verbatim for one of them.